# C# Convert exact durations (mm:ss,xx) in ss,xx

Tags: c#, time, formatting, type-conversion

My question is how to fix a fail at converting of a time span(m:ss,10th of sec.) in (ss,tenth of seconds);

The Problem is that the Output if this is completely wrong.

```
timeInString = "1:09.01";
tmpData.SetTimeDG2((Convert.ToInt32(timeInString[0] * 60) + Convert.ToInt32(timeInString.Substring(2, 2)) + (Convert.ToDouble(timeInString.Substring(5, 2))/ 100)));
```

The Output must be 69,01, but is 2949.01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the multiplication outside the parentheses:

```
Convert.ToInt32(timeInString[0]) * 60
```

---

#### Rationale

The ASCII value of `"1"` is 49, which is the key to your error and the reason this fails silently.

You start with this code:

```
Convert.ToInt32(timeInString[0] * 60)
```

This takes the single-character string `timeInString[0]` and treats it as an ASCII character for the purposes of multiplication. That is, since C# sees a multiplication sign, it expects multipliable things as operands. It sees the string and thinks, "This is a number behind-the-scenes; let's treat it as one." This amounts to saying:

```
Convert.ToInt32(49 * 60)
```

Evaluating the entire expression, you get (49 * 60) + 9 + 0.01 = 2949.01.

What you need to do is move the `* 60` outside of the parentheses.

```
tmpData.SetTimeDG2((Convert.ToInt32(timeInString[0]) * 60 + Convert.ToInt32(timeInString.Substring(2, 2)) + (Convert.ToDouble(timeInString.Substring(5, 2))/ 100)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't attempt to parse time strings on your own. Use `TimeSpan` instead:

```
string timeInString = "1:09.01"; 
TimeSpan interval;
TimeSpan.TryParseExact(timeInString, @"m\:ss\.ff", null, out interval);
Console.WriteLine("Seconds {0}", interval.TotalSeconds);
```

---

And the problem with your code is that `timeInString[0] * 60` is taking the char (unicode) value of `1` instead of the numerical value. So you'd have to parse the char first. Yet, your code would fail if you attempted to enter a string like `11:04.13`. Just don't bother parsing this on your own. It's already in the framework. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

you missed hour in your time.

if do not care hour then you must passed zero to it. flow bottom C# code:

```
        var timeInString = "0:1:09.01";
        var timeInTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(timeInString);
```